# RPC call - static methods is not working

Tags: java, gwt, rpc

I am trying to define a static method in the service interface to make an rpc call. But it doesn't allow me to do so. here I am pasting my code

Client class

```
public void sendDomesticData(String product,String dma,String yrmnths,String dist,String metrics) {
    String url = GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "domesticservice";
    domesticServiceAsync = (DomesticServiceAsync) GWT.create(DomesticService.class);
    ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) domesticServiceAsync;
    endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(url);
    domesticServiceAsync.sendDomesticData(product,dma,yrmnths,dist,metrics,new Domestichandler<Void>() );
}

public class Domestichandler<Void> implements AsyncCallback<Void> {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        String error = caught.getMessage();
        System.out.println(error);
    }

    public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        System.out.println("perfect");
    }
}

Service 
public interface DomesticService extends RemoteService {
    public  void sendDomesticData(String product,String dma,String yrmnths,String dist,String metrics);

}

public interface DomesticServiceAsync {
    void sendDomesticData(String product,String dma,String yrmnths,String dist,String metrics,AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}
```

Server side -

```
public  void sendDomesticData(String product, String dma, String yrmnths, String dist, String metrics) {
   System.out.println(product);
}
```

Basically I am trying to send the values from the front interface to the  server side and I don't want any return value. But the values passed to the server side should be stored globally in the server class so i can access those values in different method. I tried changing all the senddomestic values to static but it won't allow me to do so? why?

Comment: You marked the wrong answer as the accepted answer because it will give you errors - see my own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because RemoteServiceServlet needs to invoke your service methods somehow and the implementation expects instance methods. But this shouldn't prevent you from assigning the method data to static fields. Just be aware of multi threading.

Comment: Storing the data in static fields of your RemoteServiceServlet instance is NOT the way to go and will give you errors, because you have no control over which servlet instance it will be stored in - see my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

GWT always uses instance methods for RPC calls, static methods are not possible in this case.

What is important to understand about GWT is that any RemoteServiceServlet instances are created and maintained by the servlet container (e.g. Tomcat). The servlet container might create a number of servlet instances on startup (Tomcat creates 6 RemoteServiceServlet instances by default) and then uses load balancing to determine which servlet handles an RPC request at a particular point in time. Depending on settings of course, you have little control over which RemoteServiceServlet instance exactly will handle a specific RPC request.

Therefore, if you want to store information on the server side **globally** using RPC calls, the idea proposed by YuPPie to use static fields of your RemoteServiceServlet implementation is a BAD idea. You will have no idea which of the RemoteServiceServlet instances maintained by the server contains your static data, and any subsequent calls to retrieve the data will give erratic results.

You have a few options, though. Storing the information in a database (or something similar) is the most straightforward option, but from your post I'm guessing you want something simpler. A singleton class which holds your data is probably the way to go. A thread-safe example:

```
public class DataContainer
{
  private static DataContainer _singleton;

  private String _dataField1;

  public static synchronized DataContainer getInstance()
  {
    if (_singleton == null)
      _singleton = new DataContainer();
    return _singleton;
  }

  public synchronized String getDataField1()
  {
    return _dataField1;
  }

  public synchronized void setDataField1(String dataField1)
  {
    _dataField1 = dataField1;
  }
}
```

Then in the server side implementation of your RPC call you could do something like:

```
public void sendDomesticData(String product, String dma, String yrmnths, String dist, String metrics)
{
   DataContainer.getInstance().setDataField1(product);
}
```

This way, if there are multiple servlet instances they will all share the singleton instance of DataContainer, thus giving you a place to store your data globally. I hope this will help you.